# Passing value of spinner inside fragment

Tags: android

I have a fragment which contains a spinner. The spinner will show "90 Days","180 Days" and "365 Days'. My problem is how to pass the spinner selected item to within the fragment.

My fragment code portion is

```
      void PrevReqList(String enquiryStatusCode, final View rootView){
                final   ListView enquiriesList=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.req_list);
                lists.add(enquiriesList);


                ArrayList<String> statisticsDuration = new ArrayList<String>();
                statisticsDuration.add(getResources().getString(R.string.days90));
                statisticsDuration.add(getResources().getString(R.string.days180));
                statisticsDuration.add(getResources().getString(R.string.days365));

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.item_spinner_small_white, statisticsDuration);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner);
                listDurationSpinner =(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_duration);
                listDurationSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                listDurationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

             **How to pass from here to below?**

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }


                });

                SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Common.preferenceName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String userName=preferences.getString(Common.userName,"");
                final TextView noItems=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.no_items);
                noItems.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                final String reqtype= this.getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString(Common.REQUISITIONTYPE);
                enquiriesList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                int duration=0;
                if(listDurationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.days90))){
                    duration = 90;
                }
                else if(listDurationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.days180))){
                    duration=180;
                }
                else if(listDurationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.days365))){
                    duration=365;
                }

    // My remaining code


    }
```

Please forgive me if I made any mistake.Iam a newbie.

Comment: You can get value using `statisticsDuration.get(position)` and store in some variable global to this function and then use that variable below wherever you want.

Comment: Where you pass the spinner selected value ?

Comment: @ Abu Yousuf  bro i added "   String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();" inside onItemSelected. But how to pass or connect the value to below portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code..
make one method like below ...

```
    private void getData(String value){
    SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Common.preferenceName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String userName=preferences.getString(Common.userName,"");
    final TextView noItems=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.no_items);
    noItems.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final String reqtype= this.getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString(Common.REQUISITIONTYPE);
    enquiriesList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    int duration=0;
    if(value.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.days90))){
        duration = 90;
    }
    else if(value.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.days180))){
        duration=180;
    }
    else if(value.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.days365))){
        duration=365;
    }

}
```

after that when select item for spiner view..

```
  listDurationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  getData(parent.getSelectedItem().toString());// check this
                   //or
                  getData(spiner.getSelectedItem().toString());
               }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }


        });
```

Comment: Sir ,i added " String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();" inside onItemSelected. But how to pass or connect the value to below portion?

Comment: i don't understand means?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a data member in fragment, like this:

`String spinnerSelectedItem;`

Then, you can initialize that member in `onItemSelected()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           spinnerSelectedItem = statisticsDuration.get(position);
     }
```

Thereafter, `spinnerSelectedItem` will contain the value which was selected by the user.

Comment: @parekhkriti after the change suggsted by you, the  spinnerSelectedItem is to be  transform into final one element array

Comment: I have asked you to make that variable a datamember, i.e. you need to declare it where you declare your views